# Why is unpolarized light a statistical mixture?

Tags: optics

Why is unpolarized light a statistical mixture of pure polarizations, as it is said [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92158/partially-polarized-light-with-jones-vectors), rather than a quantum combination?

Comment: related: [Why, in spin sums, we sum over final spin states and average over initial states?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137188/).

Comment: because photons are bosons not fermions? Which is a bit like saying "because they do", a comment not really an answer.

Comment: I'm in a basic optics course, so I don't know much about bosons and I was looking for a more basic answer. But I guess what you mean is that it is a fact of life. This behaviour is observed experimentally and therefore photons are classified as bosons. Am I right?